# Trying to understand how Pandoc converts from Markdown to Latex

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I apologize if this is a repeat.

I have a Markdown file [test.md](https://www.akshaygaur.org/test.md) which has two latex math mode parts:

> First latex block (in .md file):

```
\begin{flalign}
P(1<X) &= \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) dx \nonumber \\
&= \int_{1}^{4} 0 dx + \int_{4}^{\infty} e^{-(x-4)} dx \nonumber \\
\boldsymbol{P(1<X)} &= \boldsymbol{1} \nonumber
\end{flalign}
```

> Second latex block (in .md file):

```
\begin{flalign}
Expected \; Revenue &= 2.5 \cdot non-passenger \; vehicles + 1.0 \cdot passenger \; vehicles \nonumber \\
&= \$(2.5 \cdot (25 - E(X)) + 1.0 \cdot E(X)) \nonumber \\
&= \$(62.5 - 1.5(E(X))) \nonumber \\
&= \$(62.5 - 1.5 \cdot 15) \nonumber \\
\boldsymbol{Expected \; Revenue} &= \boldsymbol{\$40} \nonumber
\end{flalign}
```

When I run the following command:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t latex test.md -s -o test.tex
```

I get the output as [test.tex](https://www.akshaygaur.org/test.tex) where the above two blocks are rendered as:

> First latex block (in .tex file):

```
\textbackslash{}begin\{flalign\} P(1\textless{}X) \&=
\int\emph{\{1\}\^{}\{\infty\} f(x) dx \nonumber \textbackslash{} \&=
\int}\{1\}\^{}\{4\} 0 dx + \int\_\{4\}\^{}\{\infty\} e\^{}\{-(x-4)\} dx
\nonumber \textbackslash{} \boldsymbol{P(1<X)} \&= \boldsymbol{1}
\nonumber \textbackslash{}end\{flalign\}
```

> Second latex block (in .tex file):

```
\begin{flalign}
Expected \; Revenue &= 2.5 \cdot non-passenger \; vehicles + 1.0 \cdot passenger \; vehicles \nonumber \\
&= \$(2.5 \cdot (25 - E(X)) + 1.0 \cdot E(X)) \nonumber \\
&= \$(62.5 - 1.5(E(X))) \nonumber \\
&= \$(62.5 - 1.5 \cdot 15) \nonumber \\
\boldsymbol{Expected \; Revenue} &= \boldsymbol{\$40} \nonumber
\end{flalign}
```

I am not sure how this happened. I am using:

OS: Windows 10

Editor: Visual Studio Code 1.28.1

Pandoc Version: 2.2.3.2

I though maybe it is because of the line endings being different in Windows so I changed the Line Endings from CLRF to LF and vice-versa but this didn't effect the output.

I would like to be able to say with certain surety as to how the conversion will happen as this is confusing to me.

I have also uploaded the files in case it is an issue of encoding of chars.

Comment: Further investigation reveals that `\int_{1}^{\infty}` seems to be the part that is causing the issues. If I remove `\int` there doesn't seem to be any issues. I don't know why though.

Comment: Also, if I don't use only `int` and remove `_{1}^{\infty}` it works. I can't get the limits of the integral to work for some reason.

Comment: Also, using `align*` instead of `flalign` also works.

Comment: So, I guess now the question is, how to left align the equations having integrals with limits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandoc's LaTeX parser is not 100% perfect, so for complicated cases like this, you should use [generic-raw-attributes](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#generic-raw-attribute) in your markdown:

````
```{=latex}
\begin{flalign}
Expected \; Revenue &= 2.5 \cdot non-passenger \; vehicles + 1.0 \cdot passenger \; vehicles \nonumber \\
&= \$(2.5 \cdot (25 - E(X)) + 1.0 \cdot E(X)) \nonumber \\
&= \$(62.5 - 1.5(E(X))) \nonumber \\
&= \$(62.5 - 1.5 \cdot 15) \nonumber \\
\boldsymbol{Expected \; Revenue} &= \boldsymbol{\$40} \nonumber
\end{flalign}
```
````