# Pandoc fails to render valid LaTeX macro definitions from markdown (and R markdown)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, markdown, knitr, pandoc

In R, I have character objects that contain LaTeX macro definitions. The
challenge is to use these objects in R Markdown documents, so that the 
macro definitions are rendered correctly when the .Rmd files are converted to 
LaTeX (and then to PDF). It is a challenge because Pandoc (v2.9.1 and 2.9.2)
fails to render some macro-generating code correctly, even when that
code is valid LaTeX.

Here is a minimal example. First, consider this Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Rendering LaTeX Macros from R Objects"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_md: true
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r}
withoutBraces <- "\\newcommand\\withoutBraces{This is a sentence.}"
withBraces    <- "\\newcommand{withBraces}{This is a sentence.}"
```

```{r, results = "asis"}
writeLines(withoutBraces)
writeLines(withBraces)
```
````

Knitting this .Rmd file from RStudio produces a .tex file that includes the 
following output:

```
\newcommand\withoutBraces{This is a sentence.}
```

but

```
\textbackslash newcommand\{withBraces\}\{This is a sentence.\}
```

In other words, the `\withoutBraces` command is rendered correctly in the .tex
document, but the `\withBraces` command is not. Inspection 
reveals that the `rmarkdown::render()` part of the knitting process is fine, in
the sense that it produces an unproblematic .md file. The problem lies with 
pandoc: when it converts the .md file to a .tex file, the `\withBraces`
command doesn't render correctly.

If I were writing .md files instead of .Rmd files, I could use "generic raw
attributes" in my code chunks to get the `\withoutBraces` macro definition to
render correctly, as in [this example from
@mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815445/697473). But I don't see a way to 
do that when working with R Markdown files. Is there anything that I can do
to get the `\withoutBraces` definition to render correctly when I am knitting 
an .Rmd file to LaTeX and PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay with a LaTeX formatting error on my part, not in any problem with pandoc. I had written

```
withBraces    <- "\\newcommand{withBraces}{This is a sentence.}"
```

when I should have written

```
withBraces    <- "\\newcommand{\\withBraces}{This is a sentence.}"
```

When I use the second string instead of the first, there is no problem with the conversion to LaTeX.